# How to store list of more than 5000 values in variable and later compare it?

Tags: java, string-comparison

There are various ways of doing the same thing however I'm looking for most efficient way here.

This is what I'm doing currently but there are going to be 5000+ entries that will all be added to `girlNames`. Not sure if its the right approach to do such thing and later compare it against given value.

Also appreciate if someone explain the logic behind why other method is better than this one.

```
Set<String> girlNames = new HashSet<String>();
girlNames.add("monica");
girlNames.add("ribeka");
girlNames.add("angelina");

String str = "angelina";
if (girlNames.contains(str.toLowerCase())) {
    System.out.println("found");
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

Comment: Do you instead want to use a database? Please consider this, especially if many such comparisons will be done.

Comment: Do you want to store this information in DB later? Searching in DB will be faster

Comment: A `HashSet` is exactly the collection type that is appropriate for such a scenario: Adding and searching are operations with O(1) time complexity.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose only if the objects stored overrides correctly `hashCode`. In case the OP use `String` it's already done but it's something to be aware of

Comment: @Tom -- got it, thanks.

Comment: @Pelocho did i make any mistake in above code. how can i make sure it overrides correct hashCode. is there any study guide to refer for right coding practice with hashset .

Comment: If you use `String` you're fine. But if using other objects and want to store them in any `Hash` structure you should override `hashCode()`. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563847/what-is-the-use-of-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Using a `HashSet` is completely fine for your purpose:

- `HashSet`s have look-up complexity of O(1) in the average case, meaning that the performance does not degrade for larger amounts of data.
- 5000 `String`s of that size can be easily kept memory. In a conservative estimate, each `String` object would require 1 KB of memory, totaling to 5 MB.