# hashCode() method

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

I need some help in better understanding `hashCode()` method in a theoretical way. I´ve read (emphasis mine):

> When `hashCode()` is called on two separate objects (which are equal according to the `equals()` method) it returns the same hash code value. **However, if it is called on two unequal objects, it will not necessarily return different integer values**.

Where can said exceptions occur?

Comment: `Apple.hashCode() != Banana.hashCode()`

Comment: My question is more dedicated to the 2nd paragraph of the question, which states:
Different objects can have the same hashCode() under certain conditions. 
(If I understood that correctly).

Comment: Yeah that is called _collision_. You could look into HashMap collisions e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691920/collision-resolution-in-java-hashmap

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473890/10819573) of [What is the use of hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563847/what-is-the-use-of-hashcode-in-java) explain it very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a class with two String fields, and that its hashcode is calculated by summing the hashcodes of those two fields. Further suppose you have an equals that simply checks whether the class fields values are equal.

```
class Test {
    String a;
    String b;

    public Test
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return a.hashCode() + b.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { // simplified
         Test other = (Test)o;
         return a.equals(other.a) && b.equals(other.b);
    }
}
```

Let's see if non-equal instances can have the same hashcode

```
Test t1 = new Test("hello", "world");
Test t2 = new Test("world", "hello");

System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));                  // false
System.out.println(t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode()); // true
```

Are we still respecting [`hashCode`'s contract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())?

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the `hashCode` method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.

Well, yes, since it only depends on `a` and `b` and we're using their `hashCode` method which we can assume respects the contract.

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

It does

```
Test t1 = new Test("hello", "world");
Test t2 = new Test("hello", "world");

System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));                  // true
System.out.println(t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode()); // true
```

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

That's what we were trying to demonstrate in the first place. It's not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int hashCode() {
  return 27;
}
```

Believe it or not, but this is, although it isn't a very efficient way of working, a valid implementation of hashCode, since it will respect the contract with the equals method. This implementation will cause exactly what you describe.

The hashCode is used to limit the number of cases to compare to.
For instance, if in a high school, you are looking for a student. You only know the name, gender and age of this student. Are you going to look through all the students, or only the ones with that age and gender?

The hashCode does the same, for certain data structures. When looking for an item, it will first make a sub-list/collection of the items with an identical hashCode, and then, it searches for the exact item within that sub-list/collection.

The more specific your hash code, the more efficient the search.